why recognize my models in an other app in django how can i call models in other app
from product.models import Product

CART_SESSION_ID = 'cart'


class Cart:
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            cart = self.session[CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart

    def __iter__(self):
        cart = self.cart.copy()

        for item in cart.values():
            item['product'] = Product.objects.get(id=int(item['id']))
            item['total'] = int(item['price']) * int(item['quantity'])
            yield item

    def unique_id_generator(self, id, color, size):
        result = f"{id} - {color} - {size}"
        return result

    def add(self, product, quantity, color, size,):
        unique = self.unique_id_generator(product.id, color, size)
        if unique not in self.cart:
            self.cart[unique] = {
                'quantity': 0,
                'price': str(product.price),
                'color': color,
                'size': size,
                'id': str(product.id),
            }
        self.cart[unique]['quantity'] += int(quantity)

        self.save()

    def save(self):
        self.session.modified = True



hi every one
i have problem in my site
i will write code Cartmodule session base in django but i have problem in my model in the other app
in the other app i have create models but i dont fetch in my other app
my error like is :
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'black'
how can i fix this error
hi every one
i have problem in my site
i will write code Cartmodule session base in django but i have problem in my model in the other app
in the other app i have create models but i dont fetch in my other app
my error like is :
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'black'
how can i fix this error

The error means that you are sending the string black to the function int() and you can't convert that string to an int.  Perhaps you can include you full traceback to pinpoint where this problem is occurring.

i think is problem to be related to my models is seem to like red line under the "from produc.models import Product"
and not fetch in my db
